# Worker threads are not being utilized in Time rewind system, is this job system really multi-threaded?

Tags: unity, multithreading, unity-job-system

I am trying to make a simple time rewind mechanic. It's working but it becomes slower as number of game objects increases. I decided to give Job System a shot. My idea is to interpolate between positions and rotations for N game objects in parallel. It is certainly running faster than single thread execution.

However, when I see the profiler, the worker threads are sitting idle.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

And here's the IJob code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[BurstCompile]
struct RewindJob : IJob
{
    public int RewindableIndex;
    [ReadOnly]
    public NativeArray<Vector3> positions;
   
    public NativeArray<Vector3> finalPositions;
    public float currentTime;

    public void Execute()
    {
       //rewind code for interpolating b/w positions
    }
}
```

and this is how I schedule RewindJob for each entity like this in main thread:

```
NativeArray<Vector3> finalPositions = new NativeArray<Vector3>(m_Objects.Count, Allocator.TempJob);

for (int i = 0; i < m_Objects.Count; i++)
{
    NativeArray<Vector3> positions = new NativeArray<Vector3>(count, Allocator.TempJob); ;

    TimeRewindable rewindable = m_Objects[i];

    for(int yo = 0; yo < count; yo++)
    {
        positions[yo] = rewindable.m_Transforms[yo].position;
    }

    RewindJob rewindJob = new RewindJob();
    rewindJob.finalPositions = finalPositions;
    rewindJob.positions = positions;
    rewindJob.RewindableIndex = i;

    JobHandle handle = rewindJob.Schedule() ;
    handle.Complete();
    positions.Dispose();
}

for(int i = 0; i < m_Objects.Count; i++)
{
    m_Objects[i].transform.position = finalPositions[i];
    m_Objects[i].transform.rotation = finalRotations[i];
}

finalPositions.Dispose();
finalRotations.Dispose();
```

What I can understand is it's not real multi-threading but context switching. Can anyone just explain a little bit what's happening? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to package up these jobs for the threads to consume?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for responding. I added some dummy code. Cannot add the full code. But you will get the idea what I am doing. Hopefully.

Comment: It looks like you're invoking a job for each object, rather than gathering the objects that need rewinding into one big collection and letting the job system blast through them in one big chunk, distributing the work between threads as it needs. Have you tried handling this in a more batch-oriented way?

Comment: You are right. I am scheduling a job for each object. I haven't tried that approach but I am taking one step at a time.  I will try it tomorrow. But can you think of any reason why job system is not giving all this work to worker threads. Is it because there's no enough data for cpu to distribute the work?

Comment: Effectively. Also, since you're demanding the results back immediately and this thread's just going to be waiting till it gets them, it might as well be the one to do the work. Think of it like an outsourcing firm. You're calling each worker, one at a time, to give them one work item, and you wait on the line until they finish it. Instead, you could send the outsourcing firm a big work order, give them a deadline of next frame, then go on with the rest of what you need to get done while they do the work. At the deadline, you pick up the finished work without ever stalling to wait for it.

Comment: @DMGregory Wow. Thank you for explaining it in a simpler way. I should take few steps back and redesign the whole thing again to keep job system in mind. Appreciated.

Comment: Sounds good! If you find an alternative way to structure the work that improves your performance, please post it as an Answer below

Answer (score 1):

When you want Unity to run multiple jobs in parallel, then you have to let it. You are scheduling multiple jobs in a loop, but each time you call

```
JobHandle handle = rewindJob.Schedule() ;
```

you immediately call

```
handle.Complete();
```

The [Complete](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Jobs.JobHandle.Complete.html)-method will wait until the job is finished. That means that your code ensures that no job will be scheduled until the previous job has completed. So what would Unity need a second worker-thread for?

If you want to give Unity a chance to run all those jobs in parallel, then

1. Create a `new NativeArray<JobHandle> handles(m_Objects.Count, Allocator.TempJob);`
2. Collect the return value of Schedule in that array
3. After you scheduled all the jobs, call [`JobHandle.CompleteAll(handles);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Jobs.JobHandle.CompleteAll.html)

Unity will then be obligated to finish all the jobs in `handles` as quickly as possible, which will probably mean that it is going to use multiple worker-threads.